# Create a txt file in phone memory on windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to know where is the right place to create a simple txt file in phone memory, in the same directory with ducuments, pictures, etc. I want to access that file from pc via usb cable. An example would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Your request is not really clear but you can use onedrive.

Comment: For example I want to programmatically create a txt file in Phone>Pictures. I can do this with KonwnFolders.Pictures? @MatDev8

Comment: I started to develop for wp 8.1 and it works